# Angular 17: Google maps

Tags: angular, google-maps

How to embed google map in Angular.
`<iframe src="...">`

I'm waiting for the correct way (they are errors) to include the Google maps map in Angular (17).

Simply so that the map addition appears.  Google maps has the option to incorporate.  But when I paste that code I get an error.

Comment: Read the following manual https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's official google maps npm package [@angular/google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps), or you can directly check the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/google-maps/README.md)